# Passing dereferenced variable to function saves memory? - C

Tags: c, pointers

Let's say I have a string.

```
char *string;
```

I want to pass this string to a function. Which one uses up less memory? This one:

```
void function(char *string)
```

Or this one:

```
void function(char **string)
```

---

First one copies the string and passes that copy to the function, while the second one passes the string's contents directly, am I correct? If that's the case, then the second option uses up less memory, right?

Also, when should I dereference a variable before passing it to a function?

Comment: No - you're confused - in both cases you are just passing a pointer (there is no copying in either case) - only the level of indirection is different.

Comment: In the second case you are passing a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: check `printf("%zu, %zu\n", sizeof(char*), sizeof(char**));`

Comment: @Lopson Could you elaborate on what exactly are you trying to do? copy strings in *the* function?

Comment: @askmish I'm merely reading the string in the function. If I were to alter its contents, should I dereference the variable before passing it?

Comment: Why would you worry about the size at all? It's just a couple of bytes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the first one only passes the address of the first `char` in the string. In fact, the second form will give you extra unnecessary overhead for your purpose.

Comment: By extra overhead, do you mean the space used by the extra pointing? Also, in situations like this when should I dereference a variable?

Comment: Besides memory overhead, you also get more overhead from extra dereferencing operations when you're accessing the string inside the function. With the first form you only need to dereference `string` once whenever you need to access a certain `char` in it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you should pass strings to a function:

```
void myfunction(char *str)
{
  printf("Unaltered string from main: %s\n",str);
  strcat(str," world");
  printf("After altering  the string from main: %s\n",str);
  return;
}

int main()
{
 char *s=(char*)malloc(128*sizeof(char));
 //handle s == NULL case
 strcpy(s,"hello");
 myfunction(s);
 printf("Changes after myfunction call: %s\n",s);
 free(s);
 return 0;
}
```

When you pass a pointer as an argument to a function, its called `call by address`, in C. In the above example, the address that the pointer `s` has in `main` is copied into the  `str` in `myfunction` when you call `myfunction(s);`. Both `str` and `s` point to the same memory, now. Whatever changes you would do with `s` in `main`, those changes will be available in `str` in `myfunction` and vice-versa.

You do not need a `**s`.